# mxgraph - Get xml data from current graph by javascript?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I want to get xml data from editor.
http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html

Does anyone know how to get xml data from mxGraph editor by javascript ?

```
var Draw = new function __Draw() {
    this.save = function () {
        var graph = new Graph();
        var encoder = new mxCodec();
        var result = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());
        var xml = encodeURIComponent(mxUtils.getXml(result));
        // var xml = mxUtils.getXml(EditorUi.editor.getGraphXml());
        console.log('xml');
        console.log(xml);

        AP.post("api/draw/server", {xml: xml}, function(code){
            if (!code.good()){
                return AP.alertError(code.message);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The commented code is the answer. editor.getGraphXml() should return the xml representation of the graph

```
var xml = mxUtils.getXml(EditorUi.editor.getGraphXml());
console.log('xml', xml);
```